# How to test the main method in a JavaFX application when a background thread is running?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have the following JavaFX application and simply want to test that the main method does not give any errors, how would I do so and should I do so?

```
public class GUISimple extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        primaryStage.setTitle("TCG Console");
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(ConsoleController.class.getResource("console.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

What I have so far:

```
public class GUISimpleTest {
    @Test
    public void testMain() {
        GUISimple.main();
    }
}
```

I have already tested the other classes, including the `ConsoleController` and GUI with TestFX. For this specific test I am using JUnit though.

The keypoint to note here though is that the `ConsoleController` starts up another thread, which is running after `GUISimple.main()` has been called.

Calling `System.exit(0)` nor `Platform.exit()` seem to exit the test. How can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

launch() is blocking the thread for JavaFX.
Start GUISimple.main() in a separate thread for example:

```
@Test
public void testMain() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Do something
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }).start();

    GUISimple.main();
}
```